# How to know if a pin is assined in raspberry pi?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, gpiozero

I'm "playing" with Django and I'm trying to read the state of a pin when a button is pressed using **gpiozero**. I'm able to do this without trouble outside Django, meaning that I can detect when the button is press without trouble. But, when I'm using Django there is a problem because when I load the page the script assign LED(17) (the way gpiozero puts the pin 17 as output for a led) without trouble, but if I reload the page there is a problem. I believe is because when I reload the page the pin is not close/clean so it tries again to assign the pin 17 as an output led an pop the next error:

```
.
.
.
(pin, reserver))
gpiozero.exc.GPIOPinInUse: pin 17 is already in use by <gpiozero.LED object on pin GPIO17, active_high=True, is_active=False>
```

Due to this, I want to know if there is a way to check if the pin is already assign before doing it, this way I could avoid this error. Thanks.

You can check the state of a pin (after assing it) with:

```
led = LED(pin)
a = led.pin.function
print("a is:",a)
>>>a is: GPIO17
```

But could not find how to do it before the first line.

BTW, I'm have the Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: DO NOT post code fragments which are meaningless out of context. Post complete code.

Comment: Oh,sorry in the error it shows a lot of thing from Django before those last lines, that is the reason why I do not write it, and because those lines are the problem. The other code was just a  way to do what I want after you define the pin. Thanks

Comment: Normally you write an example with the minimum code to show the problem. This is also a good fault finding technique.

Comment: have you tried to trap the error using `try:  except:`?

Comment: mmm let me try with Try - Except to see if it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is unanswerable without more information.

`gpiozero` usually uses `RPi.GPIO` as backend which directly maps pins using `/sys/gpiomem` and writes directly to the hardware. `RPi.GPIO` keeps its own internal information on pin use.

`gpiozero` "cleans up" its pin assignments on exit, so there is no residual assignment.

There are other methods of controlling pins, the deprecated Sysfs or the newer character device `/dev/gpiochipN` which can be interrogated.

Comment: Thanks, I will search about it to see if I find something.
And, there is more information I can provide to sort this out?